# How do I add images to a "Posts Page" in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system, html-table

I am having a weird issue. I have a Wordpress website and have created a page called "Blog" and set the template of that page to "Blog Template(Posts Page)" so that all posts are displayed on this page.

However, the client has asked me to add a few images on top of the page or on the right hand side of the page and he wants those images to be visible as well as the list of posts.

When I edit the content of the page manually by going into "Pages" -> "Edit" I put the following code to display the images but they do not get displayed and I believe it is because the template of the page is set to "Blog Template" This is the code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img alt="logo-xxx" src="xxx/wp-content/uploads/xxx.jpg" width="183" height="120" /></td>
<td><img alt="xxx" src="xxx/wp-content/uploads/xxx.jpg" width="250" height="131" /></td>
<td><img alt="xxx" src="xxx/wp-content/uploads/xxx.jpg" width="150" height="200" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please note this code works on another page so do not tell me that he code is wrong because it is not. Also, I added the XXX for security purposes.

I hope someone out there can help me solve this problem.

Comment: you are writing this in text mode or visual mode ?

Comment: text mode - and when I switch to visual I can see the images but when I publish they are not there

Comment: Were the images uploaded using Media manager or via FTP? If Media manager was used then the path doesn't look correct, Media manager will put images in /wp-content/uploads/year/month/imagename.ext, for eg: /wp-content/uploads/2013/05/xxx.jpg

Comment: Make sure the `blog` template contains the `<?php the_content(); ?>` template tag, which will/should display the content of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @Anand the path to the files is correct I just added the XXX and deleted the year snd month to keep things smple. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @diggy will it be as simple as adding that tag to the template? how will I go about doing this?Can i directly edit the blog template? Its just I have never done this and am not sure how to do it. thank you for your replies guys

Comment: You should be able to edit the template via admin > Appearance > Editor. Give it a try!

Comment: Will give it a try and get back to you @diggy Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your issue... you're using a page to post loop ¿it's right?

When you set a page to be "the loop", the content of page isn't displayed, wordpress don't use te page`s content, use a loop of posts

If you're doing by yourself the template you can add the code directly on page template (usually index.php) than loops the posts

Also can edit the index-php (or whatever be the loop template in your theme) and make a primary "read" of page content.